# Dynamic State Binding to String Literals | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

I have a very generic component whose UI auto-generates based on the predefined JSON structure. The generic component has two parts A) Meta Info and, B) Tree.

Part B (Tree) has many strings literal like **@consumer_business_name@** that will keep updating when type on the corresponding field present on Part A (Meta Info) that is bind to this literal.

As you can see in the attached image captured after every keystroke (3 times). Observe the left column `Business Name` and right side tree node subtitle `Lorem @consumer_business_name@ mmm`.

Whenever typing, the previous value of the state remains and the new value replacing in this fashion previous value + current value.

What would be the ideal generic solution to this problem?

What I want to achieve is whenever the left panel is updated then wherever in the right side associative string literal corresponding to that field is, should also get updated in realtime.

[image: Typed "1"]

[image: Typed "2"]

[image: Typed "3"]

```
  findAndUpdateTreeData1 = ( id, data, newVl ) => {
    console.log(id,newVl);
    const status = data.reduce( ( total, current ) => {
        if( current.subTitle.includes( id ) ) {
            var regex = new RegExp( "@" + id + "@" ,"ig" );
            let temp = current.subTitle.replace( regex , newVl + "@" + id + "@" );
            current.subTitle = temp;
            return true;
        }
        if ("children" in current ) {
            return total || this.findAndUpdateTreeData1( id, current.children, newVl)
        }
    }, false);
  return data;
  }

const agreementJSON = { treeData : [{title:'United States of America',children:[{title:'Chicago',id:4,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem @consumer_business_name@ mmm {this.state.test}',children:[{title:'New Mexico',id:17,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 17'}]},{title:'New York',id:3,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 3 @DANISH@'}],id:0,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem @consumer_business_name@ mmm'},{title:'United Arab Emirate',children:[{title:'Abu Dhabi',id:5,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 5'}],id:1,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 1'},{title:'United Kingdom',subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 2',children:[{title:'London',id:7,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 7'},{title:'Hampshire',id:6,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 6'}],id:2,editOn:false,subTitle:'Lorem Ipsum 2'},],configurations:["consumer_details":[{"fid":"consumer_business_name","display_text":"Business Name","value":"","default":"","type":"text","stype":"text","is_mandatory":1,"error_message":"Error*"}]}

class AgreementConsole extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = agreementJSON;
  }
}
```

Comment: maintain two datastructures, one with the template and one with the output.

Comment: Despite maintaining two ds, How can I make string 'this.state.x'  function as an object but not string. so whenever the state changes the value gets an auto update.